# How to check product is exist in current website or not?

Tags: magento2

I just want to load the product if that is available on the current website else not on the custom page. here is my code which is not working product still loading if that not exists in the current store...

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository) {

        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;

    }
public function getProduct($product_id){
    try{
        return $this->productRepository->getById($product_id,false,$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    }catch (\Exception $ex){
        $this->log($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey did you get proper collection?

Comment: I want to check using a single SKU not in the collection ... I have a solution for collection but what if I want to check by single ID and SKU

Comment: You can't check it by single id or sku. Because, addWebsiteFilter() can able to use when we load collection.

Comment: If you will use this method then, it will not affect to site speed. Because, I added filter of addFieldToFilter(). So, It's load only single record. So, you can use my answer also.

Comment: let me review again and apply code

Comment: okay............

Answer (score 0):

Replace this below code in your file :

```
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function getProduct($product_id){
    try{
        $product = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['eq' => $product_id])
            ->addWebsiteFilter('your_website_id');
        return $product;
    }catch (\Exception $ex){
        $this->log($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

After that, you can get count of collection :

```
$productId = "10";
if(count($block->getProduct($productId)) > 0)
{
   echo "Product Exist";
} else {
   echo "Product Not Exist";
}
```

Remove generated and clean cache.

Answer (score -1):

The getProduct function takes the store id and the product id as parameter and it runs the product model for that specific store.

And the getProductCollection function takes store id as parameter and returns the product collection for that specific store view.

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    ...
}

public function getProduct($storeId, $productId) {
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
                            ->load($productId);
    return $product;
}

public function getProductCollection($storeId) {
    $productCollection = $this->productFactory->create()
                                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                                    ->getCollection()
                                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $productCollection;
}
```

Comment: If above code is works for you please accept and vote up for other people to get easier to find appropriate solution

Comment: not working....

Comment: before down vote , let  me know the reason

Comment: bcz it not working...